# HTML / CSS - Center multiple divs inline

Tags: html, css

I'm try to accomplish something rather basic but I failed to succeed, so far.
I have an image and a title which should be displayed in the center of the parent selector (div). Unfortunately I don't know how to properly align them when I center both the logo and the text.

**Html:**

```
  <div class="content">
    <div class="header">
      <img src="path/to/image">
      <span>Hey this is my title</span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.header{
   text-align: center;
   width: 100%;
   height: 40px;
}
.header img{
   height: 40px;
   width: auto;
   display: inline-block;
}
.header span{
   display: inline-block;
}
```

As you can see the logo has a static width/height while the text can have a variable height.
The code above makes the styling like the example below:

[image: Example Image]

Can anyone tell me how to do this? I basically want several divs next to eachother, but all aligned in the center.

Comment: Wait... Are you trying to center both? Or the logo must always be centered? What exactly are you expecting?

Comment: If you check the image. I want the text next to the logo. But their is space between the top of the Header and the top of the Text span.

Comment: I already understood your problem and answered it as well. Kindly check...

Comment: See this pic: http://i.imgur.com/ukhDRNr.png

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you looking for `vertical-align: middle` to center vertically?

```css
.header {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
}
.header img {
  height: 40px;
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.header span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: #eef;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="header">
    <img src="//placehold.it/40?text=Logo" />
    <span>Hey this is my title</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Note:** I have added background for better visibility of the borders.

[image]

A better explanation:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use flexbox. I don't know if I correctly got that you want your items to be centered both horizontally and vertically inside header. If not just delete the `justify-content` part.

```
.header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

More info about flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/